# VSCODE cant write on terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

[image]

i has trying with `CTRL` `+` `C`, but nothing happens, i has trying restart VSCode and didnt work,

Comment: the problem has been solved on this link : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96827#issuecomment-623116041

Answer (score -1):

Click on "+" on the top right of the terminal window. From there, you can open a new terminal tab and from there close your existing one.

Comment: i has trying add new terminal window + in cmd or powershell, but still cant write

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).